# if i have 1000000 small files cache, is it optimized in performance that files scattered in many folders than store in only a folder in php?

Tags: php, file, caching

if i have 1000000 small files cache, is it optimized in performance that files scattered in many folder  than store in only a folder in php ?

Take an example.

paths of the files in a folder :

```
/var/html/www/test/cache/aa-xx-xx-01.php
/var/html/www/test/cache/aa-xx-xx-02.php
/var/html/www/test/cache/aa-xx-xx-03.php
....
```

paths of the files scattered in many folders :

```
/var/html/www/test/cache/aa/xx/xx/01.php
/var/html/www/test/cache/aa/xx/xx/02.php
/var/html/www/test/cache/aa/xx/xx/03.php
....
```

which one is better in performance in hdd and ssd?

Comment: Many folders would likely be better, as directories themselves can be read more efficiently if the list of files they contain requires fewer disk blocks to store; although you may also find that lots of small small files results in a high inode count